# JdbcTemplate update error when using with parameters

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm coding in SpringMVC database application. When I try to insert data to database with JdbcTemplate object update method with parameter and I go error while inserting data. It was fine with out parameter coding as following:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO contact (name, email, address, telephone)"
                + " VALUES ('" + contact.getName() + "', '" + contact.getEmail() + "', '" 
                + contact.getAddress() + "', '" + contact.getTelephone() + "')";
jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
```

But when I use with parameters, it got error:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO contact (name, email, address, telephone)"
                    + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
jdbcTemplate.update(sql, contact.getName(), contact.getEmail(),
                contact.getAddress(), contact.getTelephone());
```

Please help me!

Comment: The error is "HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils" .

Comment: i think your spring-core version should change.What is the version of your spring-core?

Comment: spring-core version is 3.1.1 RELEASE

Comment: Just try to update it. You may use 4.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: Thank you! It's ok now by updating spring-core version to 4.1.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 2):

You have to menditoned parameters. Check below exampls.

```
//insert with named parameter
    public void insertNamedParameter(Customer customer){

        String sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER " +
            "(CUST_ID, NAME, AGE) VALUES (:custId, :name, :age)";

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put("custId", customer.getCustId());
        parameters.put("name", customer.getName());
        parameters.put("age", customer.getAge());

        getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update(sql, parameters);

    }
```

you can refere below link for reference.

[Spring Named Parameters examples in SimpleJdbcTemplate](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-named-parameters-examples-in-simplejdbctemplate/)

Comment: **This does not work with JdbcTemplate**: the named parameters are only supported by _SimpleJdbcInsert_ and _NamedParameterJdbcTemplate_ (_SimpleJdbcTemplate_ is now deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

Use **[SimpleJdbcInsert](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsert.html)**:

```
private long addContact(Contact contact) {
    SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource()
        .addValue("name", contact.getName())
        .addValue("email", contact.getEmail())
        .addValue("address", contact.getAddress())
        .addValue("telephone", contact.getTelephone());
    return new SimpleJdbcInsert(DBConnection.getDataSource())
        .withTableName("contact")
        .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id")
        .executeAndReturnKey(params)
        .longValue();
}
```

Comment: get NamedParameterJdbcTemplate JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource); namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);

Comment: @AlexeyPavlov can you elaborate your comment?